# Storing formatted variable into MySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I had this working by simply passing the data from one variable to another like so:

```
$CalcsSets = $DisplayCalcs;
```

without the need to use the loop inside the first if() statement and it inserted the data without quotes but all of a sudden it's stopped working and I'm not sure why (it only started showing last integer), so I went with the more complex code trying to get it to work again as shown below.

Here's the complex code I'm working with:

```
for($i=1; $i<=$CalcSets; $i++){


$calculations = PerformCalc($min, $highest, $OperatorType);

echo 'Calculations performed for '.$SetText[$i];

  foreach ($calculations as $key => $DisplayCalcs) {
      echo $SetCalc[] = $DisplayCalcs.', ';  //stores calculations with ',' in 
                                            //array.
}

if($CalcSets == 1){

   for($i=0;$i<$CalcSets;$i++){
      $SetResults = $SetCalc[$i];
      echo '<strong>'.(string)$SetResults.'</strong>';              
   }
        DB_Insert($SetResults); 
}
```

What it's supposed to do is insert values in the following format (1,2,3,4,5,) into the database in a VARCHAR row but now all it shows is the last integer with no comma. I originally wanted to just store the integers and not a comma but I couldn't get it to display on the page with commas after each integer so I went this route as mentioned earlier.

I realize I'm probably going about this the wrong way, but if any of you know a much easier, and shorter, way to do what I want, I'd be extremely appreciative of the help.

Reason I'm doing it this way, is because on the results page, it needs to show in the format mentioned above.

FYI, I did check the DB row and it is still set to `VARCHAR` with a length of `10` at the moment.

**UPDATE TO MAKE INTENTIONS MORE CLEAR**

Ok, I'm going to go back to square one and try to make my intention as clear as possible. I've been rewriting this code snippet more times than I care to count and my brain is all foggy lol.

```
array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

foreach(array1 as $key => $data){
  echo $data.',';

// will display 1,2,3,4,5,6, in browser.
}

if(is_true == 1){

INSERT ALL $data values into DB here. 

}
```

That's what I'm trying to accomplish in it's simplest form, I'm just have extreme difficulty achieving my goal.

**Second Update - Topic Solved**

Apparently, the DB field had to be set to Text rather than VarChar. I guess we learn something new everyday.

Again, thanks everyone for all of your help. It was greatly appreciated!

Comment: a suggestion from a better design point of view. TEXT datatype has a limit of accepting 65536 characters; so if you don't expect your data to be that long, perhaps you might think on using VARCHAR(300)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry but I couldn't make much sense from the original code but focusing only on the last IF and the containing LOOP, I think the problem is with the assignment statement:

```
$SetResults = $SetCalc[$i];
```

It should instead use .= for concatenation. Here is how it should look:

```
if($CalcSets == 1){
   for($i=0;$i<$CalcSets;$i++){
      $SetResults .= $SetCalc[$i];
      echo '<strong>'.(string)$SetResults.'</strong>';              
   }
   DB_Insert($SetResults);
}
```

Hope it works!

I completely agree with the solution from @KemalFadillah for using the implode() method. From your code snippet, I understand that $calculations is the array that stores the main values, i.e. Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5). So you can do:

```
$calculations = PerformCalc($min, $highest, $OperatorType);
$s = implode (', ', $calculations);
DB_Insert($s);
```

I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

You are executing the last for loop only if `$calcSets == 1` and have an `$i<$calcSets` condition

---

How about doing it like this

```
$SetCalc = "";
foreach ($calculations as $key => $DisplayCalcs) {
     echo $SetCalc .= $DisplayCalcs.', ';
}
DB_Insert("(".$SetCalc.")");
```

Comment: That's right. That's because the next condition is if($CalcSets >= 2 and I only want it running once if only one $CalcSet was selected. I guess I could remove the second if() condition and just do it once. Originally that if() wasn't there just the $variable = $variable as previously mentioned.

Comment: Well then, why use a for loop if it can run only once?

Comment: I originally didn't have it looping as previously stated. It was simply passing data to another variable but that stopped working for some reason so I went this route to get it to work again. Actually, I need two if statements because the second if() statement contains special conditions allowing the user to 'select and keep' which result they want whereas running it only once does not.

Comment: Also, the reason I have it looping now is to extract the data out of $SetCalc. Basically, what I want to do is simply store the values in $DisplayCalcs into the database.

Comment: Well than if you do it only when `$CalcSets == 1` you can omit the for loop and do just `$SetResults = $SetCalc[0]`. I also edited the answer for some alternate solution, although I'm not really sure if I understand your problem correctly, is there any reason for the $SetCalc to be an array?

Comment: I'll give your solution a shot and see if it works. $SetCalc was not originally there, as previously stated. It was simply $variable = $variable to pass the data from $DisplayCalcs to the corresponding DB insert variable. That worked (as in passed all unformatted integers as one string) but for some reason, it stopped. So I instead made $SetCalc an array so I could extract the data later on in the for loop.

Comment: Nope, no go. It's doing exactly what it was doing to me earlier, only displaying the last integer and only inserting the last integer.

Comment: Try var_dump()-ing the contents of `$calculations`. Is it being filled in correctly?

Comment: Alrighty, I got it to finally work. Apparently, the DB field must be set to Text rather than VarChar. I never realized that. I thought they both basically did the same thing. In any case, thank all of you for your help, it was greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `implode()` function to format the numbers.

```
$formatted = implode(',', $calculations); // Produce 1,2,3,4,etc...
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Hey Kemal, while that works to format, I'm still only able to insert and display the last integer into the DB and I'm not sure why. For example, say the $CalcSet results are: 1,2,3,4,5, the only thing that is inserted into the DB is 5 and nothing else. When I place the insert code into the loop, everything is added but one row at a time and I want that complete string added to the DB and extracted and displayable as 1,2,3,4,5.